# 7zip not sending file to archive location

Tags: archive, 7zip

I'm having the issue when trying to set my archive file to a different location. I have 3 drives `C:`, `D:`, `E:`. When I try to compress my folders and content from, (let's say `D:`) and I want them to go to a specifically to a folder to `E:` I will go under "Compress and Email" then set my archive to `E:\...`.
For what ever reason, it will compress the items to `C:\...` then transfer it to `E:\...`
The problem is the files I'm trying to compress are far to large for my `C:` and why waste time compressing it to one drive just to transfer it to a different drive? All of drives are internal drives.